# Slow Cells.Replace function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about a small macro code. This macro make my seleceted cell a comment or code depends on ! character. I assigned it to a button. But the second part runs (ElseIf Left(Cells, 1) = "!" ...) slower than first part (If Left(Cells, 1) <>...). What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub COMMENT()

Dim Cells As Range

 For Each Cells In Range(Selection.Cells.Address)

  If Left(Cells, 1) <> "!" Then
  Cells = "!" & Cells

  ElseIf Left(Cells, 1) = "!" Then
  Cells.Replace "! ", "", xlPart

  End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space after the exclamation mark?

Comment: Why not merge them into one if statement? Start with: If Left(Cells, 1) = "!" Then Cells.Replace "! ", "", xlPart Else Cells = "!" & Cells This saves an if statement, thus should speed up your code. Also why use xlPart in replace if you are looking for the first exclamation mark?

Comment: Not necessary but it would be good if possible.

Comment: @Luuklag I try your advice but doesnt work properly. It write "!" first but, I try to push macro button again it doesn't erase "!".

Comment: change the Cells.Replace "! " with Cells.Replace "!"

Comment: @Luuklag you are right. it works ! but i cant understand that why this space changes that much difference.

Comment: Because you tell it to find exactly the combination of ! and space together, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @Luuklag exactly you're right. btw thanks for your helps Luuklag, Rory and Flephal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rory stated, the following line in your code appears to have an errant space.

> Cells.Replace "! ", "", xlPart

Try the following:

```
Sub COMMENT()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell = IIf(Left(Cell, 1) = "!", Right(Cell, Len(Cell) - 1), "!" & Cell)
    Next
End Sub
```